# If parallel trends assumption is not met for diff-in-diff analysis, why not add more interaction terms to regression model?

Tags: regression, interaction, difference-in-difference

The literature presents a violation of the parallel trends assumption as a major obstacle when performing a difference-in-differences analysis.

Why can't we model non-parallel trends by simply adding more interaction terms?

For example, given the following plot where non-parallel medical cost trends are tracked for treatment and control patient cohorts, pre- and post-treatment initiation date:

[image]

why not construct a difference-in-differences model that takes into account varying cost trends in the treatment and control cohorts?

$E(y)=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x + \beta_2 c + \beta_3cx + \beta_4p + \beta_5pc + \beta_6px + \beta_7pcx $

where 
y = cost, x = time, c = cohort (treatment=1 or control=0), and p = period (pre-trmt=0 or post-trmt=1).

We could then determine if there was a significant change in trends in both the treatment and control cohorts during the post-treatment period by checking which slope coefficients are statistically significant and performing contrast comparisons.